# How to get old active storage files to download with Rails 6.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I noticed when upgrading to Rails 6.1 that the content disposition is set with the metadata in S3. But all our files uploaded before Rails 6.1 don't have that. So what can I do?

New files contain this meta information so the file is able to be downloaded. But old files don't so you when you click to download, it doesn't work.

[image]

Code calling the rails redirect controller

```
rails_blob_url @episode.file, disposition: :attachment
```